# Kafka Kraft Connection to node -n could not be established. Broker may not be available (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Tags: apache-kafka, virtual-machine, kraft

I'm trying to deploy kafka from kraft to 3 VM, according to the instructions https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart .
But when creating topic, the following error pops up and topic is not created
Here are my server.properties

```
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=3
controller.quorum.voters=1@kfk-1:9093,2@kfk-2:9093,3@kfk-3:9093
listeners=PLAINTEXT://kfk-3:9092,CONTROLLER://kfk-3:9093
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kfk-3:9092
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/app/kafka3/data/kraft-combined-logs
metadata.log.dir=/app/kafka3/data/metadata-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
```

If you ping, the servers see each other.

What could be the mistake?

I thought that the ports were closed because if im use
`nc -vz kfk-1 9092` there will be a message  *connect to kfk-1 port 9092 (tcp) failed: Connection refused* but if you use the following actions

1. `nc -l -p 9092` on kfk-1
2. `nc kfk-1 9092` another kfk
   then writes the following, *connect to kfk-1 port 9092 (tcp) succeeded*, as far as I understood the ports are open.

Braundmer is off.
VM using proxmox

Comment: `nc -l` opens a brand new TCP port. That should fail if Kafka is actually running, which it appears it isn't. Ping isn't checking Kafka is running, or any ports are open